# Web page shows as different width in Chrome compared to Firefox on Windows

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, rendering

I have a web page which is displaying much smaller in Chrome than Firefox on Windows.  This is on the same screen. According to the Chrome developer tools and Firefug they have essentially the same computed width in pixels.

This screenshot shows both browsers (Firefox at the top/back with Chrome in front of it).  I have double-checked that both have zoom level reset to 100%.

[image: Screenshot of both brwosers simultaneously]

I have checked with both browsers in "private" mode in case there was some external plugin causing an issue.  My colleague tried on a Mac in Chrome, Firefox and Safari and they were all the same (and more similar to Firefox than Chrome on my machine).

According to the Chrome developer Tools the internal width of the main content area is 951 pixels while according to Firebug the same element has a width of 953 pixels.  The difference looks a lot more than two pixels to my eyes!

Any ideas what could be causing this and how to avoid it would be gratefully received.

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: Silly question: zoom?! From picture is hard to say and I would trust more developer console than "my eyes".

Comment: In this case I'm not sure what code I could provide. There is a live example at www.birka.se.  I suppose I could try and do a very basic page with empty boxes and see if I get the same problem, and might if i have time later.  But the basic fact of the widths being the same in pixels but the physical sizes different is the weird aspect.  I thought that the pixels per inch came from the screen resolution, not the browser

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: As I said in the question "I have double-checked that both have zoom level reset to 100%."  That is via Ctrl-0.  Also went into the view menu in FF and clicked reset zoom.  In chrome I tried Ctrl-scrollwheeel - if I go up one it says "zoom 110% and down one it says zoom"90%" so I'm fairly confident I am at zoom 100%

Comment: They appear the same width to me. Windows 7

Comment: Hmm.. Running Windows 8.1 with FF 33.0 and Chrome 37.0.2062.124 (both latest as far as I am aware).  But thanks for the info.  Maybe something weird in my settings.

Comment: I would recommend trying this on several different computers and noting your results. I think you should also check your "font-size" setting. I have noticed some browsers jack up the widths of things if the user has their "font-size" set larger (for accessibility reasons). In Chrome you can find this under settings > search for "font"

Comment: @BrianFitzGerald: Good idea.  In Chrome the font size is set as "Medium" and the page zoom as 100% in the settings.  In FF I only find a "default font size" of 16.  Setting that down to 12 affects SO but not that page (since it sets it's own font size).  increasing to "large" in Chrome has no effect either.  Will try and get some more colleagues to try on different computers

Comment: Have asked a few other people to test.  The consensus seems to be it's only on my computer!  Still not sure why, but as long as it's my fault (not the CSS or soemthing) then I'm not likely to do much more investigation.  Thansk for the suggestions everyone